# iOS UIPageControl change position

Tags: ios, position, frame, uipageviewcontroller, uipagecontrol

I have a `PageViewController`and I want to change the `UIPageControl` position (from bottom to top of the screen).

That`s my code:

```
UIPageControl *pageControl = [UIPageControl appearance];
pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
pageControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

It works but the dots are shown on the bottom and I want show them on top.

I`ve tried this:

```
pageControl.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 37);
```

and

```
 UIPageControl *pageControl = [[UIPageControl alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 198, 37)];
```

I've also tried to create a `UIPageControl` in the `Storyboard`,in that case the dots are shown on top but the dots doesn't show the current page position.

**EDIT**:

In the `Storyboard` case, I update the `currentPage` like this:

```
- (PageContentViewController *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
if (([self.pageImages count] == 0) || (index >= [self.pageImages count])) {
    return nil;
}

PageContentViewController *pageContentViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PageContentViewController"];
pageContentViewController.pageIndex = index;

self.pageControl.currentPage = index;
return pageContentViewController;
}
```

But the `index` gets crazy, never show the real `currentPage`.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: In the case where you've set it in the storyboard, are you setting the `currentPage` property of the `UIPageControl`?

Comment: Is there another view obscuring your page control?

Comment: Should be very straight forward, if you set up a test project with a single `UIPageControl` as an outlet on a view controller, you can easily set the frame anywhere and set the `currentPage` property.  What do you mean by 'the `index` gets crazy'?  Is your outlet hooked up correctly?  Have you tried setting the `numberOfPages` property to make sure you have the correct number of dots displayed?

Comment: Yes @Frankie, that's exactly what I've done. When I say "the `index` gets crazy" I mean that the dots never display the correct `index` value

Comment: I've had the same problem with crazy index values.

Answer (score 0):

You can try what i did (answer in swift, but its pretty similar for obj-c):

in your view controller that handles your paging ( the one that has the UIPageViewControllerDatasource etc.)
i place that in viewDidLoad:

```
self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 30, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.size.height - 200)
```

now the -200 value is what matters, change it to any value  you would like so that the content is higher or lower and the default PageControl will stick to that

its not exactly what you wanted but might do the job